# How to write a language with Python-like indentation in syntax?

Tags: parsing

I'm writing a tool with it's own built-in language similar to Python. I want to make indentation meaningful in the syntax (so that tabs and spaces at line beginning would represent nesting of commands).

What is the best way to do this?

I've written recursive-descent and finite automata parsers before.

Comment: Take a look at a PEG parser for Python in Katahdin: https://github.com/chrisseaton/katahdin/blob/master/library/python.kat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current [CPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython)'s parser [seems to be](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Parser/Python.asdl) generated using something called [ASDL](http://asdl.sourceforge.net/).

Regarding the indentation you're asking for, [it's done](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) using special lexer tokens called **`INDENT`** and **`DEDENT`**. To replicate that, just implement those tokens in your lexer (that is pretty easy if you use a stack to store the starting columns of previous indented lines), and then plug them into your grammar as usual (like any other keyword or operator token).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [python compiler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html) and in particular [`compiler.parse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html#compiler.parse).

Comment: It's not about python... It's about python syntax. It's just similar to it. commands are not in python. Just human readable language...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest ANTLR for any lexer/parser generation ( http://www.antlr.org ).

Also, this website ( http://erezsh.wordpress.com/2008/07/12/python-parsing-1-lexing/ ) has some more information, in particular:

> Python’s indentation cannot be solved with a DFA. (I’m still perplexed at whether it can even be solved with a context-free grammar).
>
> PyPy produced an interesting post about lexing Python (they intend to solve it using post-processing the lexer output)
>
> CPython’s tokenizer is written in C. It’s ad-hoc, hand-written, and
>   complex. It is the only official implementation of Python lexing that
>   I know of.

Comment: Some time ago I was writing a parser for simple implementation of C language, it was recursive descent parser. I don't need smth complex. It is about 30 commands.